# "Not enough memory" VMware Player 6.0.3 running OSX Mavericks

Tags: macos, windows-8.1, memory, ssd, vmware-player

As of recently I seem to be getting the following error when trying to start up my VM (OSX Mavericks) with 8GB of RAM.

"Not enough physical memory is available to power on the virtual machine with it's configured settings"

At the moment it works when I lower it to 2GB, but that's enough! It was working about a month ago, don't have a restore point that far back to check out though.

All drivers are up to date, as it Windows. RAM has just finished running Memtestx86 for 6 Hours with no issues.

Any suggestions are more than welcome!

My system specs:

Windows 8.1 Pro x64 - 
i5-4670k @ 4.8GHz (Stable, Ran 24 hours of Prime95) - 
Corsair H100i - 
32GB (4x 8GB) Corsair Vengeance DDR3 @ 1800Mhz - 
Nvidia GTX 770 4GB Gigabyte WF3 OC - 
240GB Kingston HyperX 3k SSD (Boot drive) - 
4TB WD Caviar Black (Storage, and where VM is installed) - 
Corsair AX860 PSU

Comment: Try running VMware Player 'as administrator'.  Any difference?

Comment: Unfortunately not, thanks though. Now re-installing VMware player to make sure it's not an issue with that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known issue for Windows 8.1 hosts](http://blogs.vmware.com/workstation/2014/10/workstation-10-issue-recent-microsoft-windows-8-1-update.html) when you have the [october 2014 update rollup](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2995388/en-us) installed.

The issue is [fixed with the Update to Version 10.0.4.](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws10/doc/workstation-1004-release-notes.html)